# Pass a 2D Array Index into a Function?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a loop that populates a 2D array, and I want to pass the values created by this population, into a function to do other calculations with it. I'm a beginner at C++, so clear explanations would help a lot. Here is my code:

```
for (int car = 1; car <= 27; car++) {

    int test[27][3] = {{car, mpg[car], speed[car]}};

    float speed = speed[car];

    timeGen(speed);

    cout << car << "\t" << mpg[car] << "\t" << speed[car] << endl;
}
```

This is the `timeGen` function:

```
float timeGen(float x)
{
int distance = 50;
float speed = x;
float time = distance/x;
return time;
}
```

It seems as though everything will work fine, but what happens is that I get an error saying "subscript requires array or pointer type." I'm a little confused as to what they mean. Is it telling me to create a pointer to this index, and then call the pointer in the `timeGen` function? An explanation would be great!

Thank you very much. Also, the values `mpg`, `speed`, are taken from another part of my code which works fine. Instructions on how to fix the issue I'm having right now, would be great!

Comment: Unrelated, but serious error: arrays are zero-based.

Comment: How do you define the `speed` in `speed[car]`?

Comment: You should use a different name for the `float` `speed` and for the speed array. As it is, `float speed` shadows the array speed.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have an array named `speed` before defining `float speed`, it goes out of scope right after this definition. Try this:

```
float Cur_speed = speed[car];
timeGen(Cur_speed);
```

or

```
timeGen(speed[car]); // without the float speed
```

Another thing is, at each iteration you are creating a new instance of `test`. It looks like what you really want is to have a single `test` array:

```
int test[27][3];
for (int car = 0; car < 27; car++) {
 test[car][0] = car;
 test[car][1] = mpg[car];
 test[car][2] = speed[car];
```

Make sure that `mpg` is an array with 27 elements, and always use indices from 0 to 26. Same for the `speed` array. When we say `test[car][0]`, we mean the first element of `test[car]`, which has a total of 3 elements due to your definition. Essentially, the lines `test[car][X] = Y;` do the same thing you want to do with `test[27][3] = {{car, mpg[car], speed[car]}}`, however that syntax only works when you first declare an array. And the way you write it initializes all 27 elements with the same data.

Comment: Thanks much for the answer! I have a quick question though, on the second part where you said that I'm generating another instance of "test", how would I continue the for loop? It took me a whole to figure out how to do what I have right now, so I'm a little confused at this modified version. I do understand what it's doing though, but I'm not exactly sure how to continue it after what you have already.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! A quick explanation of what the line: " test[car][0] = car;" means would be great. Also, I get this stack error when I build this: "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'test' was corrupted." This happened to me before, and I learned that it means that I have too many initializations for what is allowed.

Comment: Fixed the run-time check thing, but I would still appreciate an explanation on how "test[car][0]=car;" works.

Comment: @Carpetfizz, added some explanation, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to define **float car_speed** rather than ***float speed***. It will resolve your error.